# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 () post.php

Tags: plugins, php, posts, pages, editor

I got no error in my Admin panel
but when I define a **new editor or author role**
when the user goes the panel to edit or add new page
nothing works, no button, no page builder and nothing 
and He got this error on DEV Console

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()
post.php?post=1717&action=edit:1
```

It seems the file post.php is failed to be loaded

tried active / deactive bunch of plugins but no success
I should mention I use BE THEME which has Muffin Builder as a default theme editor

but it seems an error related to WP rather than plugins
Also I checked my php.ini

and this is my php.ini

```
allow_url_fopen = On
allow_url_include = Off
display_errors = Off
enable_dl = Off
file_uploads = On
max_execution_time = 600
max_input_time = 900
max_input_vars = 5000
memory_limit = 512M
post_max_size = 512M
session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440
session.save_path = "/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php72"
upload_max_filesize = 512M
zlib.output_compression = Off
```

I dont know what to do

Comment: set wp debug to true and see what errors you can see

Comment: I did, and no error I see on the page

Comment: its like , this is an ajax call and the page cant load post.php

Comment: my question is why it only happens on other role not admin